# Setting a static (constant) POST parameter with netflix feign

Tags: netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I'm using a REST api that requires a few fields to be set. My application should always set some of the fields to the same value. Is it possible to make those values "hard coded" in the interface with the feign definition (or somewhere else)?

My feign declaration looks like the example. Let's say I always want to use the same agent from this application. Is that doable?

```
@RequestLine("POST /files")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
default FileMetadata addFile(@Param("file_name") String fileName,
                             @Param("agent") String agent,
                             @Param("md5") String md5,
                             @Param("file_type") String fileType) {
    return new FileMetadata.Builder().build();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different alternatives, in the case you are using the Spring Annotations you could use `defaultValue` annotation property to determine the default value

```
@RequestParam(value = "agent", required = false, defaultValue = "AnyAgent") String agent
```

But in the case you are using the netflix-feign annotations, and seems it is what you are doing, you would need to add in the path, i.e. in the `@RequestLine` annotation:

```
static final String DEFAULT_VALUE_AGENT = "agent";
@RequestLine("POST /files?agent=" + DEFAULT_VALUE_AGENT)
....
```

But if you are refering to Body POST, you could do it using annotation `@Body`:

```
@RequestLine("POST /files")
@Body("%7B\"file_name\": \"{user_name}\", \"agent\":  \"" + DEFAULT_VALUE_AGENT  +"\"%7D") //... other params..
....
```

---

#### Edit

Based on the Github repository [documentation](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#static-and-default-methods), if you are using Java 8, you could do a default method which calls the other method with a param constant. Just like next

```
@RequestLine("POST /files")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
FileMetadata addFile(@Param("file_name") String fileName,
                         @Param("agent") String agent,
                         @Param("md5") String md5,
                         @Param("file_type") String fileType);

@RequestLine("POST /files")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
default FileMetadata addFileConstant(@Param("file_name") String fileName,
                         @Param("md5") String md5,
                         @Param("file_type") String fileType) {
    addFile(fileName, "constant_value", md5, fileType);
}
```

Personally, I think is more flexible than the other options I proposed before. And the idea works in POST Body as well if they are params.

Comment: Thanks! I realised before that in one of my other statements, specified as a GET in the @RequestLine annotation, I missed to specify the request line. This resulted in a POST instead of GET. I don't see why feign annotations need me to specify the request get parameters, the information is already there... Is there any API documentation or reference of feign where these kinds of behaviour is described?

Comment: The only documentation I know is here: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign. It also has some examples

Comment: please check my question, he looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620137/java-default-value-in-feign-client

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation.

The problem is solved as follows:

added this to the main api on the server that I was knocking on (i.e., on the receiving side, and not on the sending side request).

for example:

```
@RequestParam(value = "code", required = false, defaultValue = "AAA") String code
```

Required is **required = false** (instead of *required = true*).

Comment: I needed a default value for the client, the server, by architecture in and design, has no default value. To shange the server for a single client is not a good idea I would say.