# Java: default value in Feign client

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign

Tell me, how can I set the default value in a parameter in the Feign client or other?

Here is my code. I indicated the default value, but it does not work :(

Service:

```
public Price get(PricesRequest request) {
        return  priceFeignClient.get(
                       request.getPrice(),
                       request.getAddress(),
                       request.getCode(),
                       request.getCurrency()
                )
}
```

Feign client:

```
public interface PriceFeignClient {
    @GetMapping
    Price get(@RequestParam("price") String price,
              @RequestParam("address") String Address,
              @RequestParam(value = "code", required = true, defaultValue = "AAA") String code,
              @RequestParam("currency") String currency
    );
```

I want to make a default value for the **"code"** parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved as follows:

added this to the main api on the server that I was knocking on (i.e., on the receiving side, and not on the sending side request).

```
@RequestParam(value = "code", required = false, defaultValue = "AAA") String code
```

Required is **required = false** (instead of *required = true*).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this on the client side, you could try adding a default method in your FeignClient interface that passes the fixed value. For example:

```java
public interface PriceFeignClient {
    @GetMapping
    Price get(@RequestParam("price") String price,
              @RequestParam("address") String Address,
              @RequestParam("code") String code,
              @RequestParam("currency") String currency
    );

    default Price get(String price, String address, String currency) {
       return this.get(price, address, "AAA", currency);
    }
}
```

and in your service you call it as follows:

```java
public Price get(PricesRequest request) {
   return priceFeignClient.get(
                 request.getPrice(),
                 request.getAddress(),
                 request.getCurrency()
          );
}
```